# what is the command in terminal to extract text from a file

Tags: php, javascript, html, linux, terminal

hey can any one tell me to write the command in terminal to extract text from a html file using tags like <li>, <strong>, <b>, <title>, <td>...etc...and $var="strings" and javascript functions using msgstring....

->i am thinking of putting these tags in a text file...

->then i want to match the tags with the help of command of terminal...

->then i have to put that into a dump file(text)...

because...i want to change the text with language preference....

i tried with awk script and egrep too....but i got poor result...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what `pandoc` is for.

```
pandoc filename.html -f html -t plain -o filename.txt
```

As a bonus, resulting plain text is beautifully formatted.

See [Pandoc Manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html).

Answer (score 2):

Doing this with awk and egrep would probably mean using regular expressions to parse HTML. This is a bad idea. See [this famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Rather, use an HTML parser. See other answers in the link above for links to HTML parsers.

As to parsing PHP source code:

As it is structurally similar to HTML, you might be able to use a (tolerant) HTML parser. Otherwise, use a PHP parser. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118741/automatically-parsing-php-to-separate-php-code-from-html).

Comment: i need to parse not only html,,php too...                                                                                   i think egrep will work... but i am not getting the exact term....

Comment: @codaddict: Did you try scrolling the page? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use regex like this:

```
perl -pne '/<strong>(.*)?<\/strong>/;' file
```

Of course, your regex will be more complex, I guess.

Comment: like this it'll take a lot time...                                                          i have to enter each tag once and then parse it....                                                 it'll be better if i'll put all tags in a text file and match that file with the file i need to parse....

Answer (score -1):

Here is my answer.

```
egrep -i -r -f myfile.txt [path] > dumpdata.txt
```

its working. But i had to parse more by cleaning all functions of javascript and variable value of php containing strings.